# Ssis 2012, Ssisdb Catalog And Serverstorage Protection Level Errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. 

I have a package calling two Execute Package Tasks (out of process) at the same time in parallel. In turn each child package operates 26 threads in parallel Execute package Tasks (out of process) to export data from a database table to CSV...typical ETL. 
Sometimes a package will fail to execute and throw the following error:

> Error 0xC0014061 while executing package from project reference
>   package xxxxx.dtsx. The protection level, ServerStorage, cannot be
>   used when saving to this destination. The system could not verify that
>   the destination supports secure storage capability.
>   The protection level, ServerStorage, cannot be used when saving to
>   this destination. The system could not verify that the destination
>   supports secure storage capability.

***This error is intermittent***. 

It is not related to a single package and does not always error on the same package.
My packages are deployed using the project deployment model.

I think it is because of running 56 packages in parallel using the Execute Package task which is causing the issue. This problem wasn't there before when it was in SSIS 2008 which used to be called 56 packages in parallel via Execute Process Task

Has anyone ever ran into this before and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue by myself. The root cause if when the Execute Package Task was called at the same time in parallel. I could repro the error when multiple execute package tasks were triggered

Staggering multiple executions solved the problem.